# How to sort and Filter the products in magento Soap Api

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2, android

I am developing an android eCommerce application where I have to add Sort and filter option in my app. Here is my code of sort.php but its not working please help in this php script.

```
<?php
require_once('../app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento umask(0); 

if(isset($_GET["sort"])){

$sort=$_GET["sort"];

  $ids = array(); 
  Mage::app();    

     // Code to Search Product by $sort and get Product IDs
     $product_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$sort.'%'))->load();

     foreach ($product_collection as $product) {
        $product2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
        $productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');
        $price=0;
        $price2=0;
        $price=$product->getData('price');
        $price2=$product2->getFinalPrice();

           $desc=$product2->getDescription();
           if($desc==""){
            $desc="blank";
           }
           $baseImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product2->getImage());
           if($baseImageUrl=="http://prashant.com/media/catalog/product/"){
            $baseImageUrl="http://prashant.com/customApi/icon.png";
           }


         $ids[] = array(
                'productId' => $product->getId(),
                'price'      => $price,
        'name'       => $product->getData('name'),
        'imageurl'  => $baseImageUrl,
        'desc'       => $desc,
        'spprice'    => $price2,
        );
     }

    echo json_encode($ids);
    exit();
}else{
    echo "error";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: sort on the basis of name? provide error

Comment: yes..I have to sort the product according to name.

Comment: But here you are filtering by name using like